# Shopping Cart Rule issue

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, free-shipping

I have built a store where we offer free shipping over a certain order value. When I do a trial and get to that point of the checkout I note that i am given the option to check a box for free shipping or one for paid shipping even though the order is over the minimum amount. Is that how it should work or have i missed a setting? I had presumed that as the shipping was free then the paid shipping method would not show once the order was over a certain price.

I have attached a screen shot to show you what I mean.

Many thanks.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this in multiple ways:

1. Use table rates:
   [Magento documentation about table rates](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping)
2. Use a shopping cart price rule:
   [Magento documentation to add shopping cart price rule](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes)

The table rates are more flexible if you want to change the shipping rates for other countries.

For the first option go to the admin, system > configuration > shipping methods > enable and configure the table rates
For the second option go to the admin, promotions > shopping cart price rules > Make a shopping cart price rule